# Application Would You Like to Use Your Current Location! using ALAssetsLibrary

Tags: ios, metadata, exif, alassetslibrary, alasset

My application only gets image and it's metadata from ios device using **ALAssetsLibrary**. 
When application starts loading images list ios warning is shown..

***"Application" Would Like to Use Your Current Location.**
This allows access to location information in photos and videos.*

**Is there way to fix program code in such way that this warning not to be shown?** (**not** by using Setting->General....)

I think user doesn't understand why application during picking the image asks about location.

Comment: Not using ALAssetsLibrary is not an option?

Comment: Then how to get images list the same way as using uiimagepickercontroller and get metadata info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the metadata info, using assetslibrary is your only option. Using Alassetslibrary means that the user grants permission to location services. The simple reason for that is that the photos metadata might contain location/gps data.

Cheers,

Hendrik

Comment: Thanks, now i see that its imposible to hide this warning.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED: It will not request access permission in iOS 6. You can check the client's [[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion] while using ALAssetsLibrary.